# ember js anchor tag not working

Tags: html, ember.js

I'm developing my university project to `ember js` mobile application , I'm adding **navigation** menu,

**html 5 example**

```
<a href="#">
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hourglass" aria-hidden="true"></span>    
 <h3 class="nav-text">Add expenses</h3>
</a>
```

**my ember js coding part**

```
{{#link-to "Addexpenses"}}<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt" aria-hidden="true">   </span> <h3 class="nav-text">Add expenses</h3>{{/link-to}}`
```

Why does it not open  `Addexpenses.hbs` page? how can I fix it?

Comment: what is the error you are getting? can you check the console and share the information you retrieve?

Comment: sir now its working, im recreate  `Addexpenses` after its working fine, can i delete my question ?? maybe someone gonna  vote down

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `Addexpenses` route to router.js via:

```
this.route('Addexpenses');
```

Comment: Sir, im already added this, im using add this for `ember g route Addexpenses`